# how to update the top using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement the same vertical alignment from top. Or in other words I want give the same top value to all `title` fields. Or it mean it's top value should be the same.

For demo, I take a live site '****.com'

First two slides are vertically aligned. (oracle cloud Infrastructure and oracle cloud application). But third slide is not vertically aligned ('Oxford University and partner to address COVID-19 variants')

**To make all three same vertical alignment**  I follow this approach:  calculate the top of any of panel and set the top to other two panel.

I followed the above approach but my title didn't slide. Here is my code:

```
document.querySelector('#rc20p3 .rh02-pcontent').getBoundingClientRect().top
```

The result is 246px. But when I set this value in panel one and two, they are not updating top value. I am updating like this:

```
document.querySelector('#rc20p2 .rh02-ttl').style.top ="246px"
```

It is not moving down. But when I again check top value using `getBoundingClientRect` it gives last value.

Comment: can you share the relevant html, css, and js for your example

Comment: `top` makes sense only when the element is `absolute`
Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp

Comment: If it already is `absolute` then try using `!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top value is the absolutely positioned value.

> The top CSS property participates in specifying the vertical position of a positioned element. **It has no effect on non-positioned elements.** ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top))

So if you want to change it you'll need to make sure the element is absolutely positioned, and at that point you will probably need to adjust the horizontal value as well.

```
var el = document.querySelector('#rc20p2 .rh02-ttl');
var pos = el.getBoundingClientRect();
el.style.position = 'absolute';
el.style.top = "246px"
el.style.left = pos.left+'px';
```

Comment: How do you know the element is not already positioned? The OP hasn't shared any code.

Comment: Because he stated that changing the top property had no effect. The only way that could be true is if the element is not positioned.

Comment: Positioned doesn't mean "absolutely positioned". relative, sticky, fixed are all positioned. And if sticky, the top value could not have a visible effect depending on the scrolling position.

Comment: That is true, but to achieve the result OP was expecting he will need it to be absolutely positioned.